# 10 million people, population decreases by 2 percent a year, country accepts A people find A such that the population in the country increases.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I have the following question :

10 million people in a country, if the country
does not accept people from other countries its population decreases by 2 percent a year. The country accepts A people a year. How big must be A in order that the population in the country increases?

**What I did**

I think that the ODE that solves this is $x'(t)=x(t)*k+A$ since the rate of growth population depend on the current population factor $k$ and constant $A$.

I tried to use the data given, we know that (time given in years) $$0.98*x(t_0) = x(t_0 +1)$$

so we can substitute $x(t_0 +1)$ from equation above we need to find $A$ such that $$x(t_0)*0.98 + A=x(t_0)$$

We know that (general equation) :

$$x(t)=-\frac{a}{k}+Ce^{kt}$$

Therefore in the problem case:

$$-\frac{a}{k}+Ce^{kt_0}*0.98+A=-\frac{a}{k}+Ce^{kt_0}$$

Therefore :

$$ln(0.98)+ln(A)-ln(C)=0$$

Which seems unreasonable, I can't figure out what's wrong with my solution.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why is the answer not "Any number more than $2\%$ of $10$ million"?

Comment: This is the answer but I'm searching for a ODE method with $x('t)=kx(t)+A$ to understand how to translate the given data to ODE to solve questions that aren't intuitive.

Comment: @Henry You are not right - your solution assumes that you have a sudden influx of immigrants at the end of the period while it's more realistic to assume that the influx is evenly distributed accross the period of the whole year. In that case, the soluiton is not 2% of 10 million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the population $x$ is decreasing over time $t$ at a rate proportional to the population size:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-kx$$

If the initial population size is $x_0$ this leads to the following solution:

$$x=x_0e^{-kt}$$

The population at the end of $T=1$ year will be:

$$x_0(1-p)=x_0e^{-kT}$$

...which leads to:

$$kT=-\ln(1-p)\tag{1}$$

...with $p$ being the percentage of reduction.

Now assume that we have an influx of $A$ immigrants **uniformly spread over a period of *T* (1 year)**. The differnetial equation that describes change in the population size is:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-kx+\frac AT$$

The initial conditions are the same $(t=0 \implies x=x_0)$. You can easily solve this equation and the solution is:

$$x=\frac 1k\left[\frac AT-(\frac AT-kx_0)e^{-kt}\right]\tag{2}$$

Suppose that the annual influx of immigrants is sufficiently big to prevent populaiton decrease. Simply put, we want $x(T)$ to be $x_0$. Putting $t=T,x=x_0$ into (2) gives:

$$kx_0=\frac AT$$

$$A=kx_0T$$

...or, if you take (1) into account:

$$A=-x_0\ln(1-p)\tag{3}$$

In your case: $x_0=1,000,000$ and $p=0.02$. This gives:

$$A\approx20,203$$

...which is more than we expected (20,000). Also note that for the value of $A$ as in (3), $x=x_0=\text{const}$ over time.